# Are there any performance differences between Oracle Entreprise and Oracle Standard editions?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, database-performance

Someone has asserted to me that the reason why one database is performing better than another (50-100%) is because one has Enterprise Edition and the other has Standard Edition.

Given the same hardware, OS, versions and data - and only using the features available in Standard edition on both. Should you see a performance increase when moving a database to Oracle Enterprise?  Has Enterprise been streamlined or is Standard been hobbled?

Is there any Oracle documentation to back the truth about this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running it with the same configuration does not provide you with a performance gain. It is the same engine and the same optimizer and so on.

But you can configure the Enterprise version to act in parallel mode. So you can partition your table and indexes and your multi-CPU server can (theoretically) improve the performance (by factors). This also depends on the available memory for caching and if your tablespaces in partitioned mode are stored on different disks.

The partitioned/parallel mode is only available in Oracle Enterprise Edition.